# Getting a strange output from computing sin(x)

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I am trying to create a program that can compute `sin(x)` given `x` and a value `n`.

I know sin can be computed as:

```
x - x3/3! + x5/5! - x7/7! + x9/9!...
```

But the output gives me the same number every time: `-2147483648`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int);

int main() {

    int ans = 0;
    double x = 0;
    int n = 0;

    cout << "Enter x value: ";
    cin >> x;
    x = x * (3.14159 / 180);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter n value: ";
    cin >> n;

    ans = pow(x, 1 + (2 * n)) / factorial(1 + (2 * n));

    cout << ans << endl;

    return 0;
}

int factorial(int a) {
    int facts = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= a; i++) {
        facts *= i;
    }
    return facts;
}
```

Comment: A first look at `factorial()` tells me that it will always return `0` because of `int facts = 0;` which should be `int facts = 1;`. Subsequently `main()` runs into a division by zero...

Comment: Furthermore the loop in `factorial()` should start with `for (int i = 2; ......` for the same reason.

Comment: Also, have factorial return a double and declare facts a double. This will significantly extend the range of "a" that will produce viable factorials. Left to an exercise to the OP as to how large "a" is before factorial() fails.

Answer (score 2):

`facts` is initialized to 0 in your function `factorial`, so it is always returning 0. Initialize it to 1. Same goes with your loop starting to 0, multiplying `facts` with `i=0`. Try:

```
int factorial(int a) {
    int facts = 1;

    for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
        facts *= i;
    }
    return facts;
}
```